# $p_n$ is never a divisor of $n!$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I just wanted to know if this will suffice as proof, as the title suggests, I want to prove that $p_n$ is never a divisor of $n!$ unless $n=2$, and I feel like stating QED after making the following statement regarding the p-adic valuation of $n!$ for the $n^{th}$ prime, but yes this is very brief and so I need criticism of course:

$$\sum _{j=1}^{ \bigl\lfloor {\frac {\ln  \left( n \right) }{\ln 
 \left( p_{{n}} \right) }} \bigr\rfloor +1} \Bigl\lfloor {\frac {n}{{p
_{{n}}}^{j}}} \Bigr\rfloor =0 \,\,\,\,\forall n: n \gt 1 \land n \in \mathbb N
$$

Comment: Since $p_2=3$ you need not exclude $n=2$.

Comment: Ah right of course that was silly  I just panicked for a minute and threw that in because I do often make that mistake, stating something to apply  for a primes and I should exclude 2

Comment: IMO it is simpler with $p_n>n.$

Comment: Sure lol I get what you are saying but suppose for a moment that such an obvious inequality does not exist, would such an approach be considered suffice for proof?

Comment: If you compute some sums, you will notice that they actually boil down to
$$\sum _{j=1}^{ 1} \Bigl\lfloor {\frac {n}{{p
_{{n}}}^{j}}}  \Bigr\rfloor = \Bigl\lfloor {\frac {n}{{p
_{{n}}}}}  \Bigr\rfloor =0 
$$
So how do you prove the general sum formula?

Comment: well in the case of the prime for which we are determining is $p_n$, yes the upper bound of the sum is equal to the lower bound, with the term $\bigl\lfloor {\frac {\ln  \left( n \right) }{\ln 
 \left( p_{{n}} \right) }} \bigr\rfloor$ vanishing as a consequence of the simple inequality you referred to earlier, but in the case that it is another prime rather than the $n^{th}$, I would consider the computation of the Discrete Fourier Transform for $\Bigl\lfloor {\frac {n}{{p
_{{n}}}^{j}}} \Bigr\rfloor$ and showing that it's summation in $j$ over that range is equal to the value stated QED